# Why viewDidLayout only got called once on iOS 7, but several times on iOS 8

Tags: ios

I have an project using autolayout,

And I notice that after `viewWillAppear`, `viewWillLayoutSubViews` and `viewDidLayoutSubViews` pair will be called several times on iOS 8, for my case, it is 2-3 times usually.

The fist `viewDidLayoutSubViews` will get incorrect frame size, so I have to avoid for first `viewDidLayoutSubViews`, and init my views afterwards.

However, when I tested it on iOS 7, I found that only ONE  `viewWillLayoutSubViews` and `viewDidLayoutSubViews` pair got called, so my code broke again.

My question is, what is changed on iOS 8 for this behaviour?

EDIT:
I have pasted my demo code here:

In the code, _pieChart will be added to self.ChartViewCanvas, and self.ChartViewCanvas is using autolayout. _pieChart is from old project code, which is drawn without auto layout.

I was required to draw the pie chart before viewDidAppear, because drawing in viewDidAppear will have a 1 sec delay compare to other views in storyboard. This is not allowed for me.

Is there any way to know when is the final `viewDidLayoutSubViews`? Calling `[self.ChartViewCanvas addSubview:_pieChart];` multiple times will lead to lower performance, and sometimes _pieChart's drawInRect will not be called every time, so the chart is not update.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    _pieChart.delegate = self;
        if (!_pieChart) {
            _pieChart = [[PieChartView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pieRadius * 2, pieRadius * 2)];
        }else {
            [_pieChart setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pieRadius * 2, pieRadius * 2)];
        }

    //_pieChart.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    if ([_pieChart superview]) {
        [_pieChart removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [self.ChartViewCanvas addSubview:_pieChart];
}
```

Comment: It could relate to auto layout being supported in iOS8 if it is a UITableView. Otherwise something must be invalidating the layout and requesting it to do it again. It could also relate to how size classes are being used internally.

Comment: well, they are the same code that is running, that's why I am talking iOS 7 and iOS 8 difference. so even something validates the layout several times on iOS 8, why iOS 7 only needs one shot?

Comment: If you put a break point in the layout function, the stack trace each time might give you a clue?

Comment: nope..I cannot see the difference

Comment: Show your real code, seems it's not correct to guidelines.

Comment: From the order layout seems to run based on tests I did, suggest you add any views in viewWillAppear or before and only do layout updates in the layout routines.

Comment: @dimpiax, I have updated. I know there is work around, but I want to keep my code elegant. iOS 7 and iOS 8 's difference is ruining it.

Comment: @Wingzero, you code above isn't elegant first of all.
Layout subviews function isn't for changing frame of existed visual items.
And not for creating. Search and read lifecycle of view controller, and what and where need to create or change.

Comment: @dimpiax, before elegant I have to meet the product requirements first. My project is derived from an old project, and I have to use old library's code as well. Given a short time I don't have many choices. I absolutely know the lifecycle, but if I was asked to draw the chart before viewDidAppear and where am I supposed to get the correct bounds size if auto-layout is not finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably only Apple knows, but I won't deal with that too much if everything is working fine. In iOS8 Apple changed a lot view controllers (again) in they way they are presented from containers VC as for rotation and `UITraitCollections`. 
For instance UIAlertView is now a view controller, when you show one you trigger all the mechanism related to present a VC.
If this fact is creating an issue it must be said that you should not rely on how many times those methods are called because they were always be unpredictable there are too many variables to be taken into account.
 A quick and dirty solution could be wrap your code in a `dispatch_once` if you want that it will be called only one time.
If you add your view using auto layout correctly you won't see any sort of bug.

[EDIT]

Here is a little snippet about how it might look your viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //.. your stuff

    //We don't need any frame autolayout wil take care of calculating it on its pass
    _pieChart = [[PieChartView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _pieChart.delegate = self;
    _pieChart.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.ChartViewCanvas addSubview:_pieChart];
    NSDictionary *bindings = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_pieChart);
    // We create constraints to tell the view that it needs to sctretch its bounds to the superview
    NSString *formatTemplate = @"%@:|[_pieChart]|";
    for (NSString * axis in @[@"H",@"V"]) {
        NSString * format = [NSString stringWithFormat:formatTemplate,axis];
        NSArray * constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:bindings];
        [_pieChart.superview addConstraints:constraints];
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Of course that is going to call drawRect:, draw rect is called when a view is marked as dirty in the display pass, but before display is usually called the autolayout engine to calculate frames of views in needs for layout.

Comment: I just want dispatch once in final view DidLayoutSubViews, any idea?

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of operations you need to perform in that method?, because I think that if you are adding views here is not correct. Perhaps you should use viewDidLoad and add relative constraints programmatically.

Comment: I have update my question. The main problem is I have to use a chart lib code, add it in a storyboard based View, and I have to do it before viewDidAppear. The only way I have is in viewDidLayoutSubViews to get the correct size. but the first viewDidLayoutSubViews call is not correct size

Comment: In my opinion is the wrong approach, viewDidLoad is the correct place to add more views, second you should use autolayout to place them correctly, I suppose that pieRadius is related to some other view size. You can place an empty view as container in your storyboard than add your pieView inside that container, of course using constraints to say that it should fit inside the container.

Comment: yes pieRadius is determined by self.ChartViewCanvas, and self.ChartViewCanvas is autolayout based. My issue is even I add my pieChart in ViewDidLoad, I don't know the correct pieRadius, because self.ChartViewCanvas autolayout is not finished. That's why I am keep calculating pieRadius and re-add pieChart, since only after autolayout is finished, can I get the correct size to draw the view. The pieChart code rewrite drawRect and needs pieRadius

Comment: That's the reason why you should add pie view using constraints created programmatically, in this way pie view will always adapt to its superview changes.

Comment: I see, you are asking to write constraint code for pieChart to layout. However, could each viewDidLayoutSubViews trigger a drawRect of pieChart in this way?

Comment: Just curious, how many times that pieChart's frame got set? Only once after layout finished, or several times by iOS?

Comment: Each time the autolayout system find the pieChartView or its superview in need for layout. You can force the system to call autolayout to recalculate the frame or just rely on system calls

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out on my application and found the same as you: 1 call on iOS7 and 3 on iOS8. From the stack traces this seems to be down to doing double layout after `viewWillAppear` and an extra layout following `viewDidAppear` not seen on iOS7.

My suggestion would be that you add any views in `viewDidLoad` (or `viewWillAppear`), then only do layout adjustments in the layout subview runs. Based on your updated post something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  _pieChart = [[PieChartView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pieRadius * 2, pieRadius * 2)];
  [self.ChartViewCanvas addSubview:_pieChart];
  _pieChart.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [_pieChart setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pieRadius * 2, pieRadius * 2)];
}
```

For interest the difference between iOS7 and 8 calling sequence was:

**iOS7**

i) `viewWillAppear` is called.

ii) layout of subviews is called. From the stack this seems to relate to the navigation bar and animation.

ii) `viewDidAppear` is called.

**iOS8**

i) `viewWillAppear` is called.

ii) layout of subviews is called. From the stack this seems to relate to the navigation bar and animation.

iii) exact same layout with exact same stack is called again. So something in the stack must request a rerun from some point.

iv) `viewDidAppear` is called.

v) An extra layout of subviews is called. This seems driven from a transaction pushed onto the run loop.

Comment: No, viewWillAppear is not giving the correct view bounds to my chart view. My canvas view is using auto layout

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. Why do you keep removing and adding the pie chart. Can you not just add it the first time then adjust it the other times? At the moment the code sets a new frame, then removes the view then adds it back in.

Comment: Because the size for first time is wrong and I have to wait until autolayout finished

Comment: You create the pie chart first call, then you are resetting the frame on each subsequent call. Removing the pie chart and adding the same one back at the end of the function is a null op surely?

Comment: Because viewDidLayoutSubViews got called multiple times and is giving different canvas bounds size between each call, I don't know when I can get the correct size, and this is my true quesiton, how to know if all auto-layout is finished, so I can start setting my chartView's frame?